# Search query - hive or hbase or solr

Tags: search, solr, hive, hbase

Just posting this to get thoughts on what is a good choice of tool to better meet the below requirement

A large table in DB2 with state column, 2 integer columns, 1 timestamp column and 2 blob columns. The 2 blob columns have the xml gzip compressed.
The requirement is to offload this data into hadoop and be able to query based on state and/or the 2 integer columns and/or the timestamp column (combination of one or more columns).
With hive, it makes sense to partition the data based on the state column and probably bucket on the id columns. This would not be still optimal as searching just with those ids or for a time range would take longer.

Then i started to lean toward Hbase for storing this data with one of the id columns as the key, but again searching on other columns would not be optimal. Then i looked at solr to see if all the search columns can be indexed so that its faster.

I am confused on how to approach this. Any direction would be of great value.

UPDATED:

**Query Pattern**

> 1. By state
> 2. By state and id1. Latest of id1 based on timestamp column
> 3. By state, id1, id2. Latest based on timestamp column.

Comment: Though SOLR might work in your scenario, it is basically for text search engine. So you might need to look for more options, may be mongo?

Comment: We use HDP platform. What makes mongo different from HBase in this situation?

Comment: what research have you done?  it does not seem like you've looked into it much.

Comment: Did you have a performance goal?  Seems like you could do what you want directly in DB2 faster than a flat-file backed tool like Hive....

Comment: @Peter, The volume is expected to be very high that offloading to Hive may get cheaper storage. While doing that it should also be able support the queries mentioned. The performance expected need not be real time but should not be batch as well. 5 minutes may be acceptable.

Comment: @Martin, Agreed that i have not gone deeper into HBase or Solr, but given the time, i am just trying to get expert view on the problem.

Comment: The *data* volume or the *query volume* is expected to be high?  With high query volume, the CPU/memory cost of doing all the extra work Hive requires (to run your simple query slowly) could pretty quickly eclipse any money you save on storage.

Comment: Also, this sounds like a job DB2 can perform just fine without modification (well maybe dump the blobs to flat files since you're not querying them.)  If the *real* requirement is simply to dump DB2 (and colo equipment perhaps?) in favor of commodity platform-as-a-service, then what about mongo, bigtable, dynamo or redshift?  The fact that your queries are pre-defined, already disqualifies Hadoop-based solutions (they're overkill!)